# Regular expression transform obfuscated e-mail addresses Perl

Tags: regex, perl, obfuscation, substitution, deobfuscation

Preface: This is for a school assignment. I'm not trying to harvest e-mails for malicious purposes.

I need to identify, extract, and transform email addresses from a given file (as a command-line 
argument). For an obfuscated email address, I need to transform the e-mail back to a regular email address format (account-name@domain-name).

These are the obfuscation techniques I need to account for:

```
No obfuscation. An email address may be included in a pair of <>. For example, 
1. <anonym@new.efs.edu> or anonym@new.efs.edu.
2. A space MAY be added before or after (or both) the @ sign.
3. The @ sign is written as AT or at, and space is added before and after AT or at. 
4. The . sign in domain name is written as DOT or dot, and space is added before and after DOT 
or dot.
```

Currently I am just trying to account for the first technique. `"1. <anonym@new.efs.edu> or anonym@new.efs.edu."`

Here is what I have so far:

EDITED: Using the help from @ikegami

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

my @addrs;
my $re; 
open my $INFILE, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;

while( my $line = <$INFILE> ) {
     push @addrs, $line =~ /(\w+\@(?:\w+\.)*\w+)/g;

foreach $re (@addrs) {
     if ($re =~ (/$line/)) {
        print $re;
     }
}
}   


close $INFILE;
```

No longer getting an error, however getting no output.

Sample Input:

```
Email: <anonym1@efs.new.edu> email: anonym2@efs.new.edu anonym1234@new.edu
Email: anonym3 AT efs.new.edu E-mail: anonym4 at efs.new.edu test at 9:00PM
We will have a test in room 705 @ another time.
Email: anonym5 @ efs dot new dot edu what if we continue
Another test anonym6 at efs dot new dot edu
If you type a dot, it means you have finished typing all contents.
Email:anonym7 AT new DOT efs DOT edu
We can, at 10:00PM, go to library DOT or .
My gmail address is jeff.anonym@gmail DOT com
```

The output should be:

```
anonym1234@new.edu
anonym1@efs.new.edu
anonym2@efs.new.edu
anonym3@efs.new.edu
anonym4@efs.new.edu
anonym5@efs.new.edu
anonym6@efs.new.edu
anonym7@efs.new.edu
jeff.anonym@gmail.com
```

Any help/point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did it occur to you that perhaps these people made it non-trivial to parse their email addresses for a reason ?

Comment: The first `syntax` error is because of `$str =~ s\w+ @ \w+\.\W+(.\W+)*; ` where the `=~` regex operator expects delimiters, `=~ /regex/;` Beyond that you are overwriting `$str` which had nothing in it to begin with, via a foreach loop.

Comment: Oh I see @sln I updated the solution/error output. Still having problems.

Comment: @mpapec maybe I misunderstood the write-up? I revised my question. Perhaps, I'm going about this all wrong?

Comment: Wow, based on all the down votes I suppose I'm completely confused as to what I'm supposed to be doing/how to go about doing it.

Comment: @chomp There's a reason why people slightly "obfuscate" their email addresses: it's to prevent scrapers and potential spammers from being able to harvest it and use it in a malicious way.

Comment: I fully realize that, but this is for a school assignment I'm not trying to collect peoples e-mails to spam them if that's why I'm getting down voted @HamZa

Comment: However, I understand now that by asking this question it might help potential spammers in their quest to harvest emails. I did not think of this when I originally posted. If anyone would be willing to correspond with me via e-mail to help as to not give a potentially harmful solution to someone with malicious intentions I think that would solve the potential issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downvotes are probably related to the question's subject matter: You appear to be working toward a solution to the problem of subverting people's attempts to avoid having their email addresses harvested.  People usually obfuscate their addresses because they don't want them harvested.  So whatever solution you come up with can be used to violate the intent of those who posted obfuscated addresses.  However, it's not your fault the professor chose an unpopular topic.

Moving past that....

Detecting obfuscated email addresses in text is an imperfect science, and somewhat of an arms race.  Even detecting *valid* email addresses is tricky.  There will be false positives, and possibly false negatives too.  And even with a pretty good looking list of email addresses could still have addresses that may be technically correct but practically of no use.

The CPAN module Email::Address is good at parsing text for email addresses, but it comes up with false positives.  Email::Valid is good at rejecting many of those false positives.  Here's an example that produces the output you're looking for:

```
use Email::Address;
use Email::Valid;

while( <DATA> ) {
  print "$_\n" for 
    grep { Email::Valid->address( $_->address ) }
      Email::Address->parse( fix_common_obfu($_) );
}

sub fix_common_obfu {
  my $string = shift;
  $string =~ s/\s+dot\s+/./ig;        # Turn ' dot ' into '.'
  $string =~ s/\s+@\s+|\s+at\s+/@/ig; # Turn ' @ ' or ' at ' into '@'.
  return $string;
}

__DATA__
Email: <anonym1@efs.new.edu> email: anonym2@efs.new.edu anonym1234@new.edu
Email: anonym3 AT efs.new.edu E-mail: anonym4 at efs.new.edu test at 9:00PM
We will have a test in room 705 @ another time.
Email: anonym5 @ efs dot new dot edu what if we continue
Another test anonym6 at efs dot new dot edu
If you type a dot, it means you have finished typing all contents.
Email:anonym7 AT new DOT efs DOT edu
We can, at 10:00PM, go to library DOT or .
My gmail address is jeff.anonym@gmail DOT com
```

This produces the following output:

```
anonym1@efs.new.edu
anonym2@efs.new.edu
anonym1234@new.edu
anonym3@efs.new.edu
anonym4@efs.new.edu
anonym5@efs.new.edu
anonym6@efs.new.edu
anonym7@new.efs.edu
jeff.anonym@gmail.com
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a (less robust, but working) solution that avoids the use of external CPAN modules, solving the core problem using regular expressions.

```
while( <DATA> ) {
  s/\s+@\s*|\s*@\s+/@/g;    # Deal with spaces around @.
  s/\s+at\s+/@/ig;          # Deal with " at "
  s/\s+dot\s+/./ig;         # Deal with " dot "
  while (
    m/(           # Match and capture.
      [^<\s:]+    # One or more characters except <, space, or :.
      @           # Literal '@'
      \S+         # One or more non-space.
      \.          # Require a dot in the domain.
      [^>\s]+     # One or more any character except whitespace or '>'.
    )/gx          # Repeat as many matches as found, allow freeform.
  ) {
    print "$1\n";
  }
}

__DATA__
.... etc etc etc...
```

I used the `/x` modifier to allow the regular expression to be freeform (insignificant whitespace, and comments allowed).  That allowed it to be broken into smaller more legible chunks.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the help! However, when to implement this I'm getting what appears to be errors with the 
"use feature 'say';". Do I need a a specific version of perl for this? I'm working with 5.8.8 @DavidO

Comment: I've removed the use of 'say'.  It wasn't introduced to Perl until Perl 5.10, which was released almost seven years ago, in December 2007.  Your Perl version is eight years old.  Anyway, this should work fine now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using what my school gave me. Its looking like I may not be able to use " Email::Address;" either. I would try to upgrade, but I'm assuming if my professor tries to compile on his old version it won't work for him. Here's my error msg:    "Can't locate Email/Address.pm in 'AT'INC ('AT'INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8" .....(keeps going) @DavidO

Comment: Email::Address and Email::Valid are available from CPAN.  A Perl course worth its tuition would promote the use of CPAN modules, unless the exercise is specifically intended to challenge your regex-fu by making you use regexes to do things that they're not optimized to deal with. :)

Comment: But if you are not allowed to use CPAN modules to solve this, I would recommend ikegami's solution, and should probably delete mine.

Comment: I do believe its challenging my "regex-fu". Regardless, I appreciate the knowledge, and attempted help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65399/discussion-between-chomp-and-davido).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to explain what you did wrong because there's so much of it, so I'm just going to provide some correct code. This will scan for one of the types of emails:

```
my @addrs;
while ( my $line = <$INFILE> ) {
   push @addrs, $line =~ /(\w+\@(?:\w+\.)*\w+)/g;
}
```

or just

```
my @addrs;
while (<$INFILE>) {
   push @addrs, /(\w+\@(?:\w+\.)*\w+)/g;
}
```

---

Tip: Since you accept the file to read as an argument, you might as well use `<>`. Replace

```
open my $INFILE, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
while (<$INFILE>) {
    ...
}
```

with

```
while (<>) {
    ...
}
```

It will read from the files named on the command line, or STDIN if no files were provided. So it's simpler and better!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I updated my code. However, while Im getting no errors now I'm also getting no output. Perhaps, I'm not using "@addrs" correctly when I'm trying to print? @ikegami

Comment: Perhaps. How could I know? `print("$_\n") for @addrs;` would display them one per line.

Comment: it is also updated in the original post. You can see the code there. @ikegami

Comment: Yeah... No. I have no idea what that is. Use what I put in the previous comment after the loop. (PS, you don't need to tag the person who wrote the question/answer to which you are replying)